# toggleClass not working when coming from an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a webpage with a link to make an AJAX request. When the following .js comes back the `toggleClass` function does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("td").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("br");
  });
});
```

If I replace `toggleClass("br")` with something like `addClass("br")` then that does work.

Furthermore, `toggleClass` works fine if I put the .js into the html page or if I run it from the console. It seems that something about both `toggleClass` and AJAX requests together stops this code from working but I have no Earthly idea as to why that might be.

**UPDATE**

I've figured out the problem. I had accidentally included jQuery two times and so javascript from AJAX requests was being run twice. Hence why only `toggleClass` was "not working" while `addClass` and `removeClass` were.

The only mystery left is why this was only the case when the .js came from an AJAX request as opposed to when it was in the HTML itself.

Comment: td is dynamic element ? You bind it in success function ?

Comment: No, the entire `table` element comes straight from the server.

Comment: Have you checked the developer console to see if there's any Javascript execution failing, such that this Javascript is not being hit?

Comment: I have, yes. And no errors are raised. 

As mentioned in the OP if I enter the javascript into the console it works fine. Furthermore, if put something like `console.log("x");` right below `$(this).toggleClass("br");` then "x" does get output to the console.

Comment: Actually, I think I have a lead! 

When I do what I mentioned just above I notice that I get back 2 "x"s with each click -- meaning that somehow the browser is picking up two clicks -- and so is toggling on and then off again. 

This seems very bizarre given that this double clicking does not occur when I pass the .js to the browser by other means (in the html or via the console).

Comment: I see the problem -- I required jQuery twice :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the `click` handler to be on an element that is populated by the AJAX query, you have to late bind the event to a DOM element that exists before the AJAX query fires.  Let's say you have the following HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table id="populatedByAjax"></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

...and you know you're going to populate the table via AJAX.  Then we need to declare our jQuery selector like this:

```
$("#populatedByAjax").on("click", "td", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("br");
});
```

That makes sure that the `click` event is bound to any current or future `td` elements in the selector `#populatedByAjax`

Comment: No, the AJAX request consists entirely of the code I posted in the OP. The table is there from the start. 

Furthermore, I attempted what Mayank Pandeyz suggested (very similar to what you suggest) and it still did not work with `toggleClass`. I don't think it's an issue with the selector since other functions like `addClass` and `removeClass` work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements and also to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

```
$(document).on('click', '#td', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("br");
});
```